# Error Perl: Can't locate Mail/Box.pm

Tags: perl

Estoy comenzando con perl y estoy usando use `Mail::BOX` pero me da el siguiente error;

```
Can't locate Mail/Box.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Mail::Box module)
```

Pero estoy buscando documentación en Internet para instalar el modulo y no lo consigo.

Estoy trabajando con Ubuntu 16 y la version de perl es la 5.22.1

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt install libmail-box-perl
```

Cuando quieras instalar un módulo, primero mira a ver si está en el sistema de paquetes de tu sistema operativo. Si no, usa el comando cpan (o cpanm si está instalado) para hacer la instalación. Si no, en la página de metacpan, en la correspondiente al módulo Mail::Box, hay un archivo de instalación que explica el proceso de forma manual.

**[Más información en este hilo del foro perlenespanol](http://perlenespanol.com/foro/instalacion-de-modulos-y-bibliotecas-en-perl-t7875.html)**.

Comment: Gracias, de todas maneras en la pagina cpan.org explican como hacerlo, muchas gracias por tu respuesta.